# Evaluate defined Mask Identifier to its Actual Value in C#

Tags: c#, type-conversion, constants, bitmask

I have a mask defined in my C# code as:

```
public const uint GFDEVICE_OUTPUTS_REFRESH_ALL = 0xFFFFFFFF;
```

I would like to use that name (`GFDEVICE_OUTPUTS_REFRESH_ALL`) instead of the actual value (`0xFFFFFFFF`) in my config file and therefore I need to read the constant name of the mask and convert it to actual `uint` value.

Example of an entry in XML cfg file:

```
entry ="display mask" value="GFDEVICE_OUTPUTS_REFRESH_ALL"
```

When reading the config file, I want to read the string value `GFDEVICE_OUTPUTS_REFRESH_ALL` and convert to uint of `0xFFFFFFFF` at run-time.
Please note I am not using enums in my code for masks. My masks are defined as uint constants as state above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
<appSettings>
<add key="display mask" value="GFDEVICE_OUTPUTS_REFRESH_ALL=0xFFFFFFFF" />
</appSettings>
</configuration>

string value = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["display mask"];
Dictionary<string,uint> dic = new Dictionary<string,uint>();
string key = value.split('=')[0];
uint value = Convert.ToUInt(value.split('=')[1]);
```